# Change bokeh python hovertool tooltip layout

Tags: tooltip, bokeh

Is there a way to change the layout of the hovertool's tooltips? I mean, bokeh shows the standard square with some information, close to the point and linked by a small triangle.. Is there a way to change this triangle and put a line that connects the tooltip to the point but at some distance (like an annotation), but dynamic as a hovertool tooltip?

Thanks for all!!

[standard tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSvu7.png)

[New tooltip type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVtSS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but it requires quite some work. You have to create a custom subclass of `Tooltip` that renders the tooltip the way you want and a custom subclass of `HoverTool` that uses that tooltip class.

Comment: Thanks! not quite easy to implement but interesting idea.